# Algebra question on integers and rationals

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would I show that if $k$ is an integer and $k^{1/n}$ is rational, then $k$ is the $n$th power of an integer.

Hint: Find roots of $x^n-k=0$ $\longleftarrow$ why this?

Comment: `Hint( find roots of x^n-k=0 <--- why this? )` Lookup the rational root theorem.

Comment: By proving if $(\frac ab)^n = k$ and $a,b$ are integers that $b$ divides $a$.  As to the your question why the hint?  Because $x^n-k = 0\iff x^n = k$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.